# Problema no mapeamento de models do Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm

O relacionamento entre as classes do arquivo Models.py não funciona por causa da ordem das classes(acho que tem mais haver com o interpretador) segue o problema:

```
class Producao(models.Model):
    empresa= models.OneToOneField(Empresa,null=False,blank=False,on_delete= models.PROTECT)

class Assinatura(models.Model):
    producoes= models.ManyToManyField(Producao,blank=False)

class Empresa(models.Model):
    assinatura=models.ManyToManyField(Assinatura, blank=True)
```

No caso a variável `empresa` fica dando erro pois para ela a classe Empresa não existe,só que se eu colocar a classe de empresa antes da classe de Produção a variável `producoes` começa a dar erro, e independente de como eu organize sempre vai dar erro porque uma depende da outra. Como faço para conseguir fazer o mapeamento fucionar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classe "Empresa" ainda não existe quando o corpo da classe  "Producao" é processado - não é "problema" algum, é simplesmente lógica.

O Django contorna isso possibilitando que as classes do ForeignKey sejam passadas como strings, em vez do objeto classe em si - então, ele cria os relacionamentos de forma lazy, e consegue achar a verdadeira classe "Empresa" quando for de fato criar a coluna no banco.

Em outras palavras, escreva:

```
class Producao(models.Model):
    empresa= models.OneToOneField("Empresa",null=False,blank=False,on_delete= models.PROTECT)
```

no seu código e vai funcionar. (As outras classes estão declaradas em uma ordem que ele consegue usar, então isso é opcional)